# php strpos missing matches in text file

Tags: php, strpos

I've got a piece of code searching a text file for an email address, returning the two numbers on the same line.
The file looks like:

```
24/08/2017,email@test.ie,1,2
21/05/2018,test@234.com,1,2
21/05/2018,test@test.ie,2,2
```

My code currently looks like

```
$lines = file("log.txt");
$found = 0;


foreach ($lines as $line){      
    if (strpos($line, $email) !==false){
        $found = true;

        $arrayOfLine = explode(",", $line);

        $foundGroup = $arrayOfLine[2]; 
        $foundVideo = $arrayOfLine[3]; 

    }
    elseif (strpos($line, $email) ===false){
        $found = false;
    }
}
```

When I run this code, through a HTML form that takes in the email address to be searched for, it only finds matching emails if they were the last entered  - in my example above, test@234.com wouldn't return a match, but test@test.ie would. What am I missing that's preventing it from turning up matches?

Comment: Have no idea what you are doing with the `$found` var, but: https://3v4l.org/GittA

Comment: @Mike This is just a section of the larger code, the overall purpose is to create the list but I can't have duplicates, so this section searches for matches, and would show that the email exists in the file already should it find a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not terminating your loop when you find an answer, meaning it continues to run even if it found a match and overwrites any previous match. Add a `break;` after you assigned `$foundGroup` and `$foundVideo`.

You also have two evaluations checking the same thing. Set the `$found` flag to `false` at the start of the loop. If your loop fails to find a match, it'll still be false. You don't need to compare twice.

```
$found = false;

foreach ($lines as $line){      
    if (strpos($line, $email) !==false){
        $found = true;

        $arrayOfLine = explode(",", $line);

        $foundGroup = $arrayOfLine[2]; 
        $foundVideo = $arrayOfLine[3]; 
        break; // stop searching for more matches
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy to figure out.

> it only finds matching emails if they were the last entered

This is true. Why? Because you always set `$found` to `false`, unless the email address you're searching for is the last one. Even if you have found a match, you're just continuing the loop and overwriting `$found` with `false`.

Take a look at [this snippet](https://3v4l.org/A5krU) and see if you can figure it out.

You either need to break out of the loop, or stop setting `$found` this way.

```
foreach ($lines as $line){      
    if (strpos($line, $email) !==false) {
        $found = true;

        $arrayOfLine = explode(",", $line);

        $foundGroup = $arrayOfLine[2]; 
        $foundVideo = $arrayOfLine[3]; 

    }
    elseif (strpos($line, $email) ===false) {
        $found = false; // This will be run every loop!
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will continue to search for email addresses even after a match is found, which is inefficient.

Comment: Which is exactly what I described in my answer.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. Both of your examples have the same error. Either way if your answer is to have the OP "figure it out," then I suppose you could put that for every answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: Meh maybe. OP's question was *What am I missing that's preventing it from turning up matches?*, which is what I explained. Didn't give a working piece of code though, that is true.